# Coloring Edges by Value networkX - error edge_color must be a color or list of one color per edge

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I am getting the error `"edge_color must be a color or list of one color per edge"` using the code below. The dataframe `genres_grouped` is also included below.

```
# Build a dataframe with your connections
test = pd.DataFrame({'from': genres_grouped['genre_1'],
                     'to': genres_grouped['genre_2'],
                     'value': genres_grouped['owner']})
 
# Build your graph
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(test, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())
 
# Custom the nodes:
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=1500,
        edge_color=test['value'], width=10.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

Here is the `dict` version of my `DataFrame`:

```
{'from':
 {4864: 'Rap', 2129: 'Indie Rock', 1394: 'Dance & House',
  2123: 'Indie Rock', 2117: 'Indie Rock', 4827: 'Rap',
  1251: 'Country & Folk', 2284: 'Indie Rock', 2383: 'Indie Rock',
  3978: 'Pop', 4508: 'R&B', 3805: 'Pop', 3954: 'Pop',
  122: 'Alternative', 1484: 'Dance & House', 1388: 'Dance & House',
  1159: 'Country & Folk', 4480: 'R&B', 2739: 'Latin', 4030: 'Pop',
  2204: 'Indie Rock', 2115: 'Indie Rock', 4854: 'Rap', 5814: 'Rock',
  5598: 'Rock', 4595: 'Rap', 1397: 'Dance & House', 4858: 'Rap',
  116: 'Alternative', 4816: 'Rap', 3626: 'Pop', 4856: 'Rap',
  5209: 'Religious', 3823: 'Pop', 4039: 'Pop', 3967: 'Pop',
  3616: 'Pop', 1821: 'Electronica', 1830: 'Electronica',
  2303: 'Indie Rock', 4848: 'Rap', 306: 'Alternative', 4664: 'Rap',
  1827: 'Electronica', 4671: 'Rap', 5592: 'Rock', 3637: 'Pop',
  5718: 'Rock', 5583: 'Rock', 4849: 'Rap'}, 'to': {4864: 'R&B',
  2129: 'Alternative', 1394: 'Electronica', 2123: 'Alternative',
  2117: 'Alternative', 4827: 'Pop', 1251: 'Rock', 2284: 'Pop',
  2383: 'Rock', 3978: 'Rap', 4508: 'Rap', 3805: 'IndieRock',
  3954: 'R&B', 122: 'IndieRock', 1484: 'Pop', 1388: 'Electronica',
  1159: 'Pop', 4480: 'Pop', 2739: '-', 4030: 'Rock', 2204: 'Electronica',
  2115: 'Alternative', 4854: 'R&B', 5814: 'Pop', 5598: 'Alternative',
  4595: '-', 1397: 'Electronica', 4858: 'R&B', 116: 'IndieRock',
  4816: 'Pop', 3626: 'Alternative', 4856: 'R&B', 5209: '-',
  3823: 'IndieRock', 4039: 'Rock', 3967: 'Rap', 3616: '-',
  1821: 'Dance&House', 1830: 'Dance&House', 2303: 'Pop', 4848: 'R&B',
  306: 'Rock', 4664: 'Dance&House', 1827: 'Dance&House',
  4671: 'Dance&House', 5592: 'Alternative', 3637: 'Alternative',
  5718: 'IndieRock', 5583: '-', 4849: 'R&B'
},
 'value': {4864: 15477, 2129: 13102, 1394: 10800, 2123: 9981, 2117: 7233,
  4827: 6895, 1251: 4550, 2284: 4480, 2383: 4366, 3978: 4299, 4508: 3620,
  3805: 3339, 3954: 3075, 122: 2975, 1484: 2961, 1388: 2733, 1159: 2725,
  4480: 2689, 2739: 2660, 4030: 2627, 2204: 2590, 2115: 2561, 4854: 2550,
  5814: 2491, 5598: 2487, 4595: 2328, 1397: 2327, 4858: 2268, 116: 2265,
  4816: 2201, 3626: 2133, 4856: 2129, 5209: 2113, 3823: 2063, 4039: 1895,
  3967: 1837, 3616: 1812, 1821: 1759, 1830: 1726, 2303: 1683, 4848: 1671,
  306: 1671, 4664: 1653, 1827: 1648, 4671: 1646, 5592: 1586, 3637: 1548,
  5718: 1514, 5583: 1493, 4849: 1481
}}
```

Any idea why I'd be getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Though the text of my error message is a bit different, I believe you are getting the error because the shape of `test['value']` which is `(50, )` is different than the required shape.  However you specify colors, the object you pass to needs to be the same length as the number of edges.  `len(G.edges)` outputs `24`.

The bit that you're missing is that when building the graph with `nx.Graph()`, networkx does not add a new edge if that edge is already present in the graph.  Since you have duplicate pairs present in your `'from'` and `'to'` columns (for example, there are multiple rows with `'from' = 'Rap'` and `'to' = 'Pop'`), the duplicates will not be added as an additional edge.

So you have to decide two things:

1. Should duplicate rows result in an additional, parallel edge?  If so, then you need to use `create_using=nx.MultiGraph()` when building your graph.
2. Does node order matter?  I.e. is `'from' = 'Rap, 'to' = 'Pop'` distinct from `'from' = 'Pop', 'to' = 'Rap'`? If so, then you need to use `create_using=nx.DiGraph()` when building your graph.

If *both* 1 and 2 above are true then you need to use `create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph()`.  Visualizing these more complex graph types deserves its own question, so I won't describe it here.

Once you've answered questions 1 and 2, however, you need to work with your input data to decide how to potentially group the `'to'` and `'from'` columns and sum the `value` column.